# How/when does JaCoCo create .exec files?

Tags: android, jacoco

This is the configuration for `JaCoCo` in my `build.gradle` and my project (`app`) includes a `library` module which is where this `JaCoCo` config is specified since the `app` contains nothing but the `Application` class.

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec")
}
```

However, I am not sure how/when the `testDebugUnitTest.exec` is created the first time since I execute the build like so:

`./gradlew clean jacocoTestReport`

and because of `clean` in the above command, the `.exec` gets wiped out. For now, I manually copy it over to that location since I don't understand how/when that `.exec` gets generated.

And this is output in logcat for when I run this command:

> Task :myLibrary:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
>   14:10:16.642 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :myLibrary:jacocoTestReport' started
>   14:10:16.642 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':myLibrary:jacocoTestReport'
>   14:10:16.642 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree] file or directory '/path/code/android/myLibrary/build/jacoco', not found

Comment: Does the `.exec` get generated after the `test` task runs?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this](https://medium.com/@android2ee/playing-with-gradle-3-and-some-few-code-coverage-on-android-with-jacoco-47df7c9328ae) post I understood that the `exec` and `ec` are created when we first run the `jacocoTestReport` task (defined in `build.gradle`):

> Now, each time you run your tests, those tasks are executed and jacoco will generate the raw file of the coverage report for this set of tests in a specific format. Exec for unit tests and ec for instrumented tests, you can find them in your build folder.